# How to propagate changes to analysis services after updating the database

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, business-intelligence

I changed dimension table (what i did? i changed the length of a column in SQL Server 2008R2).
When i try to deploy my cube in analysis services, it doesn't work !!

i checked the column length in analysis services it stil keep the old length value, then i would like to propagate this change between sql server and analysis services without having impact to other dimension tables or fact tables?

> The column length in SQL Server is : 300 but still the old one 150 in
>   SSAS

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the DataSource View right click on "refresh".  This will update the columns in SSAS.

Comment: Please be aware that you still have to manually edit the data type of the attribute in case it was already used before, as BIDS does not automatically propagate this change to the attribute! TO do this, you edit the dimension object.

Answer (score 0):

Referesh DSV & then goto that dimension and change size of that field in dimension property (SIZE) as you changes on SQL table.

Answer (score 0):

to get this to work for me I

1.) refreshed the data source view

2.) right clicked the dimension and viewed the xml code and manually changed the length in here as well, as 1 alone did not work, and could not find the property size attribute described in previous answers